# How to write an output dataframe from R directly into Microsoft Onedrive worksheet?

Tags: r, excel, onedrive

As of now I am writing data frame output into CSV file, and then manually updating it on Onedrive. Is there a way to access Onedrive and write output to onedrive sheet directly?